# Facing "checking whether the C compiler works... no" error on running autogen.sh

Tags: c, macos, gcc, linker

I am trying to build the p0sixspwn jailbreak from its source (https://github.com/p0sixspwn/p0sixspwn) in order to learn. I checked its install process and could understand that it involves running the autogen.sh and then the *configure* file and finally use *make* to build final executable.

As of now, when I run ./autogen.sh, the following error is shown:

```
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for libimobiledevice-1.0 >= 1.1.0... yes
checking for libplist >= 0.15... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libplist >= 0.15) were not met:

No package 'libplist' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables libplist_CFLAGS
and libplist_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

Details of libplist - output of brew info:

```
$ brew info libplist
libplist: stable 2.2.0, HEAD
Library for Apple Binary- and XML-Property Lists
https://www.libimobiledevice.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/2.2.0 (31 files, 408.5KB) *
  Built from source on 2021-01-05 at 11:25:57
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-core/blob/HEAD/Formula/libplist.rb
License: LGPL-2.1
==> Dependencies
Build: autoconf ✔, automake ✔, libtool ✔, pkg-config ✔
==> Options
--HEAD
    Install HEAD version
==> Analytics
install: 13,355 (30 days), 47,611 (90 days), 244,136 (365 days)
install-on-request: 1,858 (30 days), 5,447 (90 days), 16,506 (365 days)
build-error: 0 (30 days)
```

I am on Mac OS X El Capitan.

How may I proceed with this? Please point me to the right direction on why this occurs, as i want to understand the working.

Comment: It is unusual for `autogen.sh` to invoke `configure`.  It is also odd to see calls to both `autoconf` and `autoreconf`.  (Typically, the entire chain of `aclocal; autoheader; autoconf; automake` is replaced with a single call to `autoreconf`.)  I would be wary of the use of the autotools in this package.

Comment: Have you looked in `config.log`?  I would suspect that `/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/2.2.0` is a non-standard location (ie, your toolchain is not configured to look there).  You should either set PKG_CONFIG_PATH or LDFLAGS, etc.

Comment: @WilliamPursell I did look into config.log. I'm finding the same there as well. Also tried to export LDFLAGS=/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/, but it resulted in another error. The question included those details but wasnt getting any responses, so I edited to this. Would you like me to share the config.log file via pastebin?

Comment: This is the new error on setting the above LDFLAGS:                                     checking for awk... awk
checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
checking whether make supports nested variables... yes
checking whether make supports the include directive... yes (GNU style)
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in /Users/mac/Documents/Pk/Temp/p0sixspwn-copy:
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See config.log for more details

Comment: You would need something like `LDFLAGS=-L/p/a/t/h`, but if the package is using pkg-config, you may prefer to set PKG_CONFIG_PATH. (if libplist installs a pkg config file)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I added the LDFLAGS as you suggested. `$ echo $LDFLAGS` gives 
`-L/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib`. But it still causes the same error. Looking further, `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` has no value set. The `ls /usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib/pkgconfig/` gives 
`libplist++-2.0.pc libplist-2.0.pc`. In order to set the PKG_CONFIG_PATH, I read on how to set it and found this is the command: `echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`. I set this and ran again, but still without success...

Comment: Looks like you omitted `/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib` from PKG_CONFIG_PATH.   Include it in the colon separated list.

Comment: I added like so: `echo "export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib" >> ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc` and on `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` gets `/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib`. Still getting the error. But on another terminal tag i tried `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` but got black response. Is that normal?

Comment: The other shell will not update its environment until you source ~/.bashrc.  Include the trailing 'pkconfig' in the path.  That is, use `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib`.  (I doubt that `/usr/local/lib` is necessary, but I dislike pkg-config and generally leave PKG_CONFIG_PATH unset.)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I tried that as well. `echo $PKG_CONFIG_PATH` gives
`/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib`. Getting the error. It really bewilders me, as to how this works and I really want to learn how it works. I added the entire output to a shareable link so that you could take a look into what I'm doing wrong > (https://controlc.com/853b4608)

Comment: @WilliamPursell I read the configure.ac script file in the repository and could find that there is explicit checking for the libplist module like so: `PKG_CHECK_MODULES(libplist, libplist >= 0.15)`. With `/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig:/usr/local/lib` in the `$PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, the module should be recognized, but unfortunately its still not. I very much appreciate your support, but would you be so kind to discuss this over chat, at your convenience?

Comment: line 1 `liboolize: command not found`.  That may not be a problem, and merely indicates that `autogen.sh` is poorly written.  What is the version of libplist shown in the .pc file?  From the config.log, it looks like it may just be a version mismatch.

Comment: The version shown in the .pc file in the `/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib/pkgconfig` was 2.2.1 (which was identified using `cat libplist-2.0.pc`). This is the full [config.log](https://controlc.com/579f35b2) file.

Comment: I see `ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=-L/usr/local/Cellar/libplist/HEAD-7b1ccb4/lib/pkgconfig` in the config.log.  It looks like you have the path to libplist's pkgconfig in LDFLAGS.  That shouldn't break anything, but it's not needed.

Comment: Also: `Package libplist was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libplist.pc'`  Maybe you're hitting the same issue as in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59737255/how-to-get-pkg-config-to-use-pkg-config-path.

Comment: @WilliamPursell That question was informative. And i did try out the commands as in that question. But on reading the answer, i found that the `pkg-config --version` on my mac is 0.29.2 which seems to be in the correct range apparently.